# Turn Cursor Effect on/off with a toggle switch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, portfolio

I am making my portfolio website currently. I have added a flashlight cursor effect from (https://codemyui.com/flashlight-mouse-pointer/). I have also added a toggle switch from codemyui also.
I am wondering if anyone knows how to link the effect & toggle together so that when I press the switch - the cursor effect turns off?

THANKS !!

[Homepage with cursor effect & toggle switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nnXM.png)

Comment: Can you please share some code of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is set a new class on `<html>` element when toggle switch is on and apply torch effect only when such class is present:

```js
function update(e)
{
  var x = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientX : e.clientX;
  var y = e.touches ? e.touches[0].clientY : e.clientY;

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorX', x + 'px')
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cursorY', y + 'px')
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove',update)
document.addEventListener('touchmove',update)

const torchInput = document.getElementById("torch");
torchInput.addEventListener("input", torchToggle);
function torchToggle()
{
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle("torch", torchInput.checked);
}

torchToggle();
```

```css
/* Flashlight Overlay */
:root.torch {
  cursor: none;
  --cursorX: 50vw;
  --cursorY: 50vh;
}
:root.torch:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle 10vmax at var(--cursorX) var(--cursorY),
    rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
    rgba(0,0,0,.5) 80%,
    rgba(0,0,0,.95) 100%
  )
}






html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.mid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top:1em;
}


/* Switch starts here */
.rocker {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /*
  SIZE OF SWITCH
  ==============
  All sizes are in em - therefore
  changing the font-size here
  will change the size of the switch.
  See .rocker-small below as example.
  */
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888;
  width: 7em;
  height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid #eee;
}

.rocker-small {
  font-size: 0.75em; /* Sizes the switch */
  margin: 1em;
}

.rocker::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  border: 0.5em solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.rocker input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.switch-left,
.switch-right {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 3em;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.switch-left {
  height: 2.4em;
  width: 2.75em;
  left: 0.85em;
  bottom: 0.4em;
  background-color: #ddd;
  transform: rotate(15deg) skewX(15deg);
}

.switch-right {
  right: 0.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #bd5757;
  color: #fff;
}

.switch-left::before,
.switch-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.4em;
  height: 2.45em;
  bottom: -0.45em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transform: skewY(-65deg);
}

.switch-left::before {
  left: -0.4em;
}

.switch-right::before {
  right: -0.375em;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: skewY(65deg);
}

input:checked + .switch-left {
  background-color: #0084d0;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 3em;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
}

input:checked + .switch-left::before {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 3.0833em;
}

input:checked + .switch-left + .switch-right {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #888;
  bottom: 0.4em;
  right: 0.8em;
  height: 2.4em;
  width: 2.75em;
  transform: rotate(-15deg) skewX(-15deg);
}

input:checked + .switch-left + .switch-right::before {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Keyboard Users */
input:focus + .switch-left {
  color: #333;
}

input:checked:focus + .switch-left {
  color: #fff;
}

input:focus + .switch-left + .switch-right {
  color: #fff;
}

input:checked:focus + .switch-left + .switch-right {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="mid">

  <label class="rocker">
    <input id="torch" type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="switch-left">On</span>
    <span class="switch-right">Off</span>
  </label>

</div>

<!-- Any website -->

<header>
  <h1>Hidden Website</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <section>
    <article>
      <h2>Hidden Headline</h2>
      <p>test</p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>footer content</footer>
```

Comment: You are amazing. I hope you have a great life. Eternally thankful